# Selection Box on Mouse Move event

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I am trying to draw a selection rectangle around a "shot" that I have marked on a target.  I'm trying to get it to fire when it within "range" of the "shot", but it seems to randomly show up.  Below is an image of what I want (red selection rectangle around the shot when the mouse hovers over it) along with my code.

[image: Red Rectangle is the "selection" rectangle]

```
 Dim r As Rectangle

Dim shotList As New List(Of Point)
Dim scaleList As New List(Of Point)
Dim ShotCount As New List(Of Point)
Dim shotListBounds As New List(Of Rectangle)



Private Sub DrawShotHover(g As Graphics, location As Point, ByVal radius As Integer)
    Dim pn As New Pen(Brushes.Red, 2)
    Dim dashValues As Single() = {2, 1, 2, 1}
    pn.DashPattern = dashValues
    g.DrawRectangle(pn, New Rectangle(location.X - radius, location.Y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2))

End Sub

 Private Sub mPictureBox_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles mPictureBox.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then

             If shotFlag = True Then

            Dim shot As New Point(e.X, e.Y)
            shotList.Add(shot)

            r = New Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, e.X + cboCaliber.EditValue / pLineDist() / 2, e.Y + cboCaliber.EditValue / pLineDist() / 2)
            shotListBounds.Add(r)

            shotDist = ShotDistance(shot)
            mPictureBox.Invalidate()

        End If
End Sub

 Private Sub mPictureBox_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles mPictureBox.Paint


    If LineScaleVal > 0 Then
        'SELECTION RECT
        If shotHoverSel = True Then
            DrawShotHover(e.Graphics, r.Location, cboCaliber.EditValue / pLineDist() / 2)
        End If

        'Point of Aim FLAG
        Dim _poa As New POA(e.Graphics, New Point(_poaX, _poaY), cboCaliber.EditValue / pLineDist() / 2)

        'SHOT FLAG
        For Each b As Point In shotList
            Dim _Bullet As New Bullet(e.Graphics, b, cboCaliber.EditValue / pLineDist() / 2, n)
        Next 
End Sub


 Private Sub mPictureBox_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles mPictureBox.MouseMove
   If shotListBounds.Count > 0 Then
        For Each r As Rectangle In shotListBounds
            Dim rad As Decimal = cboCaliber.EditValue / pLineDist()
            If e.X >= r.X AndAlso e.X <= r.X + rad AndAlso e.Y >= r.Y AndAlso e.Y <= r.Y + rad Then
                shotHoverSel = True
                selShot = r.Location
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub mPictureBox_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mPictureBox.MouseEnter
    If shotHoverSel = True Then
        mPictureBox.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub



 Private Sub mPictureBox_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mPictureBox.MouseLeave
    If shotHoverSel = False Then
        mPictureBox.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an event for this called MouseEnter. Make a method that handles mPictureBox.MouseEnter

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that out.

Comment: I believe the mouse enter event is fired when you enter a control. I'm "entering" coordinates of a drawn rectangle (GDI+).

Comment: So I tried the mouseenter/mouseleave events to no avail.  The rectangle only highlights the last clicked shot, though the mouse move event will fire when the mouse moves over the shot.  The rectangle just wont draw though...